# is Rollover logic of TimeBasedRollingPolicy correct?

Tags: log4j, rollingfileappender

Documentation says that 'if file names haven't changed, no rollover'.fileName is derived with the fileName pattern String.

I have two observations :

1)If today appender doesn't have message to write then it wont roll the file even if triggring time has passed (i.e. we have a log file which was modified yesterday ).

2)If the yesterdays log file is 0KB(means yesterday no log was written in file) & today appender have some messages to write then it rolls the 0kb file and writes data to newly created log file

I wanted to discuss whether above both cases are correctly implemented by **TimeBasedRollingPolicy** class OR should the implementation be changed ?

My implementation strategy for 1st Scenario would be '*if FileNamePattern is set to %d{dd-MM-yyyy} then at the midnight file should be rolled irrespective whether appender has data to write if yesterday's file is non empty.*'

In case of 2nd case *if yesterday's file is 0kb means no message was logged yesterday then it should write data into same file* . because main purpose of rolling is to take backup of the logs and if file is empty *is it worth to roll it* ?

#### take below configuration of log4j.properties file as referenec for above two scenario's discussion

```
Sample log4j.properties 
####### Root Logger ########################################
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR,CA,FA

############################################################
################### APPENDERS ##############################
############################################################
# CA is set to be a ConsoleAppender  
log4j.appender.CA=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p %t %c: %m%n

# FA is set to be a FileAppender 
log4j.appender.FA=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FA.RollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy
log4j.appender.FA.RollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=.\\logs\\application.log-%d{dd-MM-yyyy}
log4j.appender.FA.File=.\\logs\\application.log
log4j.appender.FA.layout=org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout
log4j.appender.FA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p %t %c: %m%n
log4j.appender.FA.Append=true
```